# How to Fetch the component id using the component Name through JIRA REST API in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jira-rest-api

I am working on a script where I need to fetch the component id of all stories where Component label is R TEST 4.4 is attached using JIRA REST API in groovy for any project.

I am trying the below code

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

final String USAGE =
  "Usage: -Djira.username=xxx -Djira.password=xxx -Djira.Component=R TEST 4.4"

String jiraUsername = 'ABCDEF'
String jiraPassword = '**************'
String jiraComponent = 'R TEST 4.4'

println "Getting issues..."
if (!jiraUsername?.trim()) {
    fail("Empty property: jira.username " + USAGE)
}

if (!jiraPassword?.trim()) {
    fail("Empty property: jira.password " + USAGE)
}

if (!jiraComponent?.trim()) {
     fail("Empty property: jira.component " + USAGE)
}

final String JIRA_SEARCH_URL = "https://jira.testing.com/rest/api/latest/"
// see JIRA docs about search:
// https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp1389824
String JQL = "project = ABCD"
JQL += " AND issuetype in standardIssueTypes()"
JQL += " AND status in (Resolved, Closed)"
JQL += " AND component = \"${jiraComponent}\""

def jira = new RESTClient(JIRA_SEARCH_URL)

def query = [:]
query['os_username'] = jiraUsername
query['os_password'] = jiraPassword
query['jql'] = JQL
query['startAt'] = 0
query['maxResults'] = 1000

try {
    def resp = jira.get(path: "search",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        query: query)
    resp.status == 200
    (resp.data instanceof net.sf.json.JSON)
    resp.data.ids.each { id ->
        println id.key
    }
    println "Total id's: " + resp.data.total
} catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException e) {
    if (e.response.status == 400) {
        // HTTP 400: Bad Request, JIRA JQL error
        fail("JIRA query failed: ${e.response.data}", e)
    } else {
        fail("Failure HTTP status ${e.response.status}", e)
    }

}
```

But this code is giving me the below error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript5.fail() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException) values: [JIRA query failed: [errorMessages:[The value 'R TEST 4.4' does not exist for the field 'component'.], errors:[:]], ...]
Possible solutions: wait(), find(), any(), wait(long), wait(long, int), main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

In JIRA UI I can see the below value of the Compoenet/s field:

M Doc, R ABC 4.3 (Early Access), R TEST 4.4

REST API URL
    https://jira.testing.com/rest/api/2/component/595","id":"595","name":"R TEST 4.4"

So basically I want this id 595 wherever this R TEST 4.4 is attached.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your script, but you're almost there:

1) there is no `fail` method, but you call it at 2 places, you should either create one or report errors differently.

2) (at least with my Jira version) There is no property `ids` under `resp.data`. I think you want to loop on `issues` property.

3) Properties `fixVersion` and `component` are actually arrays (and the key names are plural)

So to fix points 2 & 3 you can do that:

```
def resp = jira.get(path: "search",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    query: query)
assert resp.status == 200
resp.data.issues.each { issue ->
    println "${issue.key} : components:${issue.fields.components*.name} + fixVersions:${issue.fields.fixVersions*.name}"
}
println "Total issues: " + resp.data.total
```

I'm using Groovy's spread-dot operator (`*.`) to get the names of components and fixVersions, because the lists are not lists of Strings, but lists of objects with a `name` property.

Alternatively, if you are certain there is always 0 or 1 (but not several) fixVersion, you can do that:

```
println "${issue.key} components: ${issue.fields.components*.name} fixVersion:${issue.fields.fixVersions[0]?.name}"
```

It will print null if there is no fixVersion set.